# how to add emojis panel to Extjs project

Tags: jquery, extjs, sencha-architect

any idea how to integrate jQuery.emojiarea with Extjs sencha, or if there is any other library to add emojis to my extjs project

Comment: Classic or modern toolkit, which version?

Comment: @ArthurRubens classic, extjs 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('Ext.form.FormPanel', {
            title: 'Sample TextArea',
            width: 400,
            bodyPadding: 10,
            dockedItems: [{
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                items: [{
                    text: "Show Form Values",
                    handler: function () {
                        var formPanel = this.up('form');
                        console.log(formPanel.getValues());
                    }
                }]
            }],
            items: [{
                xtype: 'textareafield',
                grow: true,
                name: 'message',
                fieldLabel: 'Message',
                labelAlign: 'top',
                anchor: '100%',
                value: "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet :smile:",
                listeners: {
                    afterrender: function (textArea) {
                        $('#' + textArea.getId()).emojiarea({
                            button: '#emojiesButton'
                        });
                    }
                }
            }],
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
    }
});
```

And the fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/36vs

Comment: thank you this is very helpful, but actually what i was trying to do is to add an emoji picker for a textarea anyidea how to do that